# NODE.JS Routing issue while following angular fundamental course

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

When trying to access URL http://localhost:8000/data/event/1
I am getting an error saying

> Cannot GET /data/event/1

My web server js code is below and following it I have provided the directory structure. Looks to be a routing problem but I'm not able to what's wrong.

I am looking to serve JSON file using node.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var events = require('./eventsController');
var app = express();
var rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../');
console.log(__dirname);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static( rootPath + '/app'));


app.get('data/event/:id',events.get);
app.post('data/event/:id',events.save);

app.listen(8000);
console.log('Listening on port ' + 8000 + '...')
```

Directory Structure

```
DemoApp
 app
  css
  data
    event
      1.json
      2.json
 scripts
    node_modules
    eventsController
    web-server
```

EventController Sample get code

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.get = function(req, res) {
    var event = fs.readFileSync('app/data/event/' + req.params.id + '.json', 'utf8');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(event);
};
```

Comment: This looks fine overall. Do you see any errors in your node console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the way you've defined your routes, they need a leading `/`

```
// Incorrect
app.get('data/event/:id',events.get);
app.post('data/event/:id',events.save);

// Correct
app.get('/data/event/:id',events.get);
app.post('/data/event/:id',events.save);
```

One more comment on how you're reading the file. I wouldn't use `fs.readFileSync()` within your route. This will block your entire server from handling requests/responding until reading the file is complete. Instead I would use the async version and then respond from the callback of `fs.readFile()`.

```
module.exports.get = (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('app/data/event/' + req.params.id + '.json', 'utf8', (err, json) => {
      // If an error occurred reading the file
      // send back a 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
      if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);

      // Return a JSON response
      // automatically sets Content-Type to application/json
      return res.json(json);
    });
};
```

Comment: Would like to know why someone downvoted? Comment explaining why would be appreciated.

Comment: @Abhi9 Glad it helped, if this was the answer, mark it as the answer so people know in the future that this solved the issue.

Comment: Yep i did. Just out of curiosity. Is there a case where it would have worked without putting slash. Just trying to understand.

Comment: @Abhi9 Not 100% sure tbh, my guess is yes if you're using `app.mountpath('/')` but everything in express has to be relative to the application root. Express uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) you could go through the docs and experiment with that package if you were interested in finding out more about how Express does pattern matching for routes.